How to non-Repeat the code that do the same thing on Visual Basic
I have a question about repeating code. I made an example with a Random Number Generator
Public Class Form1
    Dim Random As New Random
    Dim Value(20) As Integer
    Dim Number As Integer

    Private Sub Bt_Random_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Bt_Random.Click
        For i = 1 To 6 Step 1
            Number = Random.Next(60)
            Value(i) = Number
        Next
        Label1.Text = Value(1)
        Label2.Text = Value(2)
        Label3.Text = Value(3)
        Label4.Text = Value(4)
        Label5.Text = Value(5)
        Label6.Text = Value(6)
        Label7.Text = Value(7)
        Label8.Text = Value(8)
        Label9.Text = Value(9)
        Label10.Text = Value(10)
        Label11.Text = Value(11)
        Label12.Text = Value(12)
        Label13.Text = Value(13)
        Label14.Text = Value(14)
        Label15.Text = Value(15)
        Label16.Text = Value(16)
        Label17.Text = Value(17)
        Label18.Text = Value(18)
        Label19.Text = Value(19)
        Label20.Text = Value(20)
    End Sub
End Class

My question is: How can I UN-repeat the code so many times like this example? Thanks!
I just tried to make loops with For & Next, but didn't work :(
